# Updating a single LazyColumn item on state changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, lazycolumn

I need to show favourite sessions in my `LazyRow` which is item of `LazyColumn`, but if the favourites sessions list cahnges, to update the content in the `LazyRow` I need to scroll down while `LazyRow` is  completely disappears at the top, and then return to my `LazyRow`.

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun SessionsScreen(onSessionClick: (Session) -> Unit, viewModel: SessionsViewModel = 
hiltViewModel()) {
    val sessionsStateFlow by viewModel.sessionsStateFlow.collectAsState()
    val favouriteStateFlow by viewModel.favouritesStateFlow.collectAsState()

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        favourite(favouriteStateFlow)
    }
}


fun LazyListScope.favourite(favouritesState: List<Session>) {
    item {
        LazyRow {
            if (favouritesState.isEmpty()) {
                item { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.no_favourites)) }
            }
            items(favouritesState) {
                Favourite(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show `favouriteStateFlow` implementation in your `viewModel` and how do you modify it?

Comment: I'm already solved this problem. The issue was that I'm don't change `favouritesStateFlow` object itself, and I just add one more item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

To update the content in the LazyRow when the list of favorite sessions changes, you should make use of the key parameter in the items function. This ensures that Compose can differentiate between different items and update them correctly.

```
    @Composable
    fun SessionsScreen(onSessionClick: (Session) -> Unit, viewModel: SessionsViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
        val sessionsStateFlow by viewModel.sessionsStateFlow.collectAsState()
        val favouriteStateFlow by viewModel.favouritesStateFlow.collectAsState()
    
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            favourite(favouriteStateFlow)
        }
    }
    
    fun LazyListScope.favourite(favouritesState: List<Session>) {
        item {
            LazyRow {
                if (favouritesState.isEmpty()) {
                    item { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.no_favourites)) }
                }
                items(favouritesState) { session ->
                    Favourite(session, key = session.id) {
                        // Add any interaction logic here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Composable
    fun Favourite(session: Session, onClick: () -> Unit) {
        // Your Favourite item composable content here
        // For example:
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp)
                .clickable { onClick() }
        ) {
            Text(text = session.title)
        }

}
```

Comment: This is not solve of my problem, because it provides keys for `LazyRow`'s `items` function, and issue is that `LazyColumn` don't update an item which is root of `fun LazyListScopre.favourites()`